# Adding profile image in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I currently, have 2 database. images & users.

In my user Model I have:

```
    var $belongsTo=array(
    'Image'=>array('className'=>'Image')
);
```

In my image Model I have:

```
    var $hasOne =array(
    'Users'=>array('className'=>'User')
);
```

I want to achieve the following below:
My users database has a field 'image_id' and it is linked to my images database field 'id'.
Example: 
images database id = 1
users database image_id = 1

Below is the code for the add function in my image_controller. I want to add a particular image and I want the images 'id' to be save to the users database 'image_id'. How do I achieve this?

```
    function add() {
    $this->layout = "mainLayout";      
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Image->create();

        if ($this->Image->save($this->data)) {

            $user_id = $this->User->getUserInfo($this->Auth->user('id'));
            $this->data['User']['image_id'] = $user_id;

            $this->Session->setFlash('The image has been saved', true);
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'profile'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The image could not be saved. Please, try again.', true);
        }
    }

    $current_user_pic =$this->User->getUserInfo($this->Auth->user('id'));
    $this->set(compact('current_user_pic')); 
}
```

Comment: if your relations (hasone and belongsto) is correct then everything what you need it is just use 'saveAll' instead 'save', hope you understand me (:

Comment: I am not sure how to implement it. The relations works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it User hasOne Image (Image hasOne User is just semantically weird). So when you save an image record, just set the 'user_id' to $this->Auth->user('id')) before saving.

Also, don't use `var $uses = array('User','Image');` When you already set the relationship, you can access Image model through User model: `$this->User->Image->save($this->data)`

Edit: Ok, so remove the image_id field in users table, add user_id field to images table. If you use bake command to generate code, you might want to save your code in the models, controllers, and views for users and images, then re-bake these 2. Declare relationships: User hasOne Image and Image belongsTo User (I assume you know how to do that).

When you save the image, set `$this->data['Image']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id')` before `$this->User->Image->save($this->data)`

Comment: now the user id is reflecting in the image table, but when I want to add another image, the image table is not updating the new image added.

Comment: I want it to be whenever a new image is added, the user_id remains the same and the img_file changes to the new image file.